# Computer screen stops working after installing graphics driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

I have a Dell studio 1558 laptop with Windows 7 ultimate. Yesterday i got a blue screen with error for "atikmpag.sys" file and the screen stopped working. It just went blank. Later i hooked it up to external monitor and again got the same blue screen on startup. Now if i remove the graphics driver using safe mode, the screen starts working and it boots up also. But if i install the driver again i get blue screen on windows startup.  Could it be that my graphics card has gone bad ?

My pc config is
intel i5 processor, 4gb ram, amd ati radeon hd 5470 graphic card

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's gone bad, However let's keep in mind physical damage could always be a possibility. We will leave this as a last resort. Instead let's assume we have compatibility issues, since you were able to operate just fine in safe mode. Your decision to troubleshoot using safe mode is a great idea, unfortunately, I'm afraid you didn't follow through. Let's try this again, but this time, while in safe mode, check your event logs. (Right click My Computer -> Manage -> Event Logs -> **Application**) Go through them taking notes of the time stamps to track down potential errors associated with your issue, Update your answer with any relevant data. Key things would be event ids and fault codes/stop codes (Those in the format of 0x0000000). Good luck.